How can I use google task API using HTTP request with micropython on raspberry Pico?
I'm trying to add new task on my Google task list using a raspberry Pico and micropython. (I try to monitor a water tank level and remember to fill it).
I'm trying to do that using this document: Google task API
I failed to authenticate.
I try this code to retrieve tasks in my task list, before trying to insert a new one:
from WiFiNetwork import WiFi
import urequests as requests


#Network Initialization
network = WiFi()
ip = network.ConnectWiFi()

tasklist = "My_Tasklist_ID"
API_KEY = "My_API_Key"

url2=f"https://tasks.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{tasklist}/tasks&key={API_KEY}" #give me status_code 404
url3=f"https://tasks.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{tasklist}/tasks" #give me status_code 401: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."

res = requests.get(url2)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)
res = requests.get(url3)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)

The connection to the Wi-Fi is OK.
I successfully request from other URL, but it seems I don't know how to use API key with Google API...
I also create ID clients OAuth 2.0 credential/token, but I don't know how to use it...
Maybe there is another way, easier...
